# Use value of variable instead of fixed value

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code from paypal and need a small change made but don't know where to start.

```
    <script async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=myID" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="Courier Fee" 
    ***data-amount="22.00"*** 
    data-callback="https://my.website" 
>
</script>
```

I need the data-amount="22.00" changed to the value of the variable "fee"

Comment: And where is the variable fee defined? Is it a PHP or a javascript vairable?

Comment: This comes from another <script>
Does this matter or can it still be used?

Comment: I tried the same, using data-amount= fee . https://jsfiddle.net/9n667qbL/

Comment: The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.